# Windows server 2012 shared folder

Tags: windows-server-2012

I'm new to Win Server 2012. I'm trynashare a folder.
In the options, I only want to set the "Sharing Autorisations" but not the "Security" permissions. From what I read on technet, this should only give sharing autorisations to users that try to access to the file **over the network** ie in the same domain. 
My problem is that for example :
- I give to "All" the read permission in "Sharing Autorisations"
- I don't set ANYTHING for "All" in the "Security" tab of the folder.

Result : Users can't enven acces the folder.

What's going on ?

Answer (score 1):

The user must be member of the share permission AND the NTFS security permission.

You can remove ALL users, but your user must be there, with a group or directly in it somehow.

It's like having a house with a alarm system in it, even if the user can enter the house with a copy of the key, if you don't give him the alarm system code, he's toast anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Share permissions and ntfs permissions are 2 completely different things.

You need proper permissions on both in order to gain the desired access.

NTFS permissions restrict access to your files and folders in general in regard to the Filesystem.

If you want to access a folder or read a file you need proper permissions.

Those permissions are set in ACL of your files/folders.

You can view the ACL of an object if you right klick, properties, security.

Share permissions define who can access your shared folders over the network via its shared path.

If you give a user permission on file system level (ntfs) but not on share, the user could access said files if he is logged on locally on the fileserver but not via network share.

If you grant permission on share level but not Filesystem, the user is in theory able to access files via network, but is restricted by ntfs rights.

So both permissions have to be set.

Permissions apply by principle of least privilege. That means that if a user has full access on share but read only on ntfs permissions, the user can just read the files as file system does not allow writing.

Accordingly if a user has full control on ntfs permissions but read only on share permissions, the user can only read files if access via network.

Because my english is a bit rusty I hope it's clear what I want to say.

Hope that helps.